No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' available
When i run my Spring application i get NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.
The application afterwards works fine, but I'm worried it may cause unexpected errors in the future.
Stacktrace:
16:49:18.003 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.s.a.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor - Could not find unique TaskExecutor bean. Continuing search for an Executor bean named 'taskExecutor'
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: applicationTaskExecutor,springCloudAzureCredentialTaskExecutor,taskScheduler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.getDefaultExecutor(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:244)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.getDefaultExecutor(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$configure$2(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:124)
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.determineAsyncExecutor(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.invoke(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at com.medsys.medsysapi.security.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$1.deleteExpiredTokens(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124)
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


WebSecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000 * 60)
    public void foo() {
        ...
    }

}

I have already reviewed other threads concerning this issue, but they all refer only to code-defined objects like Executor / TaskExecutor. In my application, besides TaskScheduler, I also use the spring-cloud-azure-starter plugin, and as a result, springCloudAzureCredentialTaskExecutor also appears.

It is DEBUG information hence you have excessive logging. There are multiple and as you can see it will look for one with a specific name. Just don't use DEBUG logging when running your app on real environments it will only flood your output.

@M.Deinum You're right, when running the application in a different environment (with level INFO logging), this exception doesn't appear. So, does that mean I have nothing to worry about?

I think Spring throws the exception when trying to run your foo() method asynchronously and cannot choose which of the 3 available beans to use. My guess is that your code does not run properly and you need to fix it. At least I would try to fix it.

You don't have anything to worry about. It is just an informational message telling you what spring is doing.

@M.Deinum but which bean of the multiple found will Spring use then?

The one marked with @Primary which is I think the applicationTaskManager. Just debug and you will see the one used. Again it is DEBUG information and just an internal message what is happening during startup. As long as it isn't a WARN or ERROR you shouldn't worry.

Your issue is that you have 3 different bean implementations of TaskExecutor:

applicationTaskExecutor
springCloudAzureCredentialTaskExecutor
taskScheduler

So when Spring tries to run asynchronously:
    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000 * 60)
    public void foo() {
        ...
    }

it does not know which bean of the 3 available to use and then the exception gets thrown. I do not think the application runs fine if Spring is throwing that exception. Ideally you need to tell Spring which one to use. As alternatives you can use @Primary or Qualifier, see link.
